# html5 video redisplay poster image onMouseOut

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

How can I 'stop' a html5 video playback, and revert to poster image? Until `this.play()` is called, the poster image is showing properly.

My code:

```
<video loop="loop" onMouseOver="this.play();" onMouseOut="this.pause();" poster="/oceans-clip.thumb.jpg">
    <source src="/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

This is working as expected, however I want to revert to poster image onMouseOut instead of just pausing the video. What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#attr-video-poster) rules this out:

> the poster frame should not be shown again after a frame of video has been shown

I.e. if you want behaviour different to the spec you'll need to implement it yourself, maybe by using an element that overlays the video which contains the desired image and then hide/show it.

Comment: So there is no way to 'unload' the video, and revert to initial state using javascript?

Comment: Sure. You could do the equivalent of 'video.src = "";'.

Comment: You could also just say `video.load()`

Comment: Video.load() breaks the buffer events if you have custom controls.

Answer (score 9):

I've been googling for solution for this problem and apparently,

Steve Lacey's solution:

> Sure. You could do the equivalent of 'video.src = "";

appears to work on my OSX 10.9, in browsers: Safari 7.0, Firefox 26.0 and Chrome 31. I haven't tested it on mobile devices though.

I've tested it using video object created with JS:

```
var object = document.createElement("video");
/// ... some setup like poster image, size, position etc. goes here...
/// now, add sources:
var sourceMP4 = document.createElement("source"); 
sourceMP4.type = "video/mp4";
sourceMP4.src = "path-to-video-file.mp4";
object.appendChild(sourceMP4);
//// same approach add ogg/ogv and webm sources
```

Now when I want to stop video and show poster again, I just do:

```
object.pause();
object.src = "";
```

But, that's not enough since video will not be able to play again. To make it playable after this point, I removed 'src' attribute (while leaving 'source' sub-objects as is):

```
object.removeAttribute("src");
```

After this it works:

1. play video
2. on stopping video, poster will re-appear
3. can play same video again

Comment: `element.src = ''; element.removeAttribute('src');` indeed does the trick in all browsers. Thanks!

Comment: hey Sinisa, i was using your method on my html video. but it still won't back to the image part. here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/efk8L/5/) do you mind take a look for that? thanks! especially take a look for JS resetVideo() method.! thanks!

Comment: @JavaLeave I checked and I am not sure if once you click and video starts playing, next click event is handled at all. I can see that vid and vid2 and vid3 all point to same div. Is that intended like that? Even if I put return; in imageClickPlay() function video still plays when clicked?

Comment: @Sinisa the imageClickPlay() function suppose to be when you click the image, the video will either play or pause.

Comment: @JavaLeave I see but my understanding of this question was how to return poster when video is stopped, correct? (sorry for my delayed response, I just logged in here after a very long time)

Answer (score 9):

This post is old but I had the same problema and solve it like this.

```
onmouseout="this.load();"
```

Comment: Pretty simple but excellent solution, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

i used it and it is good with me

```
$('container video').hover(function () {$(this).get(0).play();}
   ,function () {$(this).get(0).load();});});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<div class="rollover">
  <video class="thevideo" loop poster="" height="100" width="250">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" >
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

<script>
    var figure = $(".rollover").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

    function hoverVideo(e) {  
        $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
    }

    function hideVideo(e) {
        $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
        v=$('video', this).get(0).currentSrc;
        $('video', this).get(0).src = "";
        $('video', this).get(0).src = v;   
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -6):

### You can use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function videostop() {
      window.location.reload()
    }
    </script>
```

That will not really stop your video, it will reload the whole document.
The "Poster Frame" will be shown.

Richie

> P.S. I'm from Germany.
>   Sorry if my English is bad.
>   But I think, my JavaScript is OK :-)

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Reloading the entire document is overkill. And it will wipe the rest of the content on the page.